# Create BE Initiative, BE Feature and CPM Feature using Rally Rest Client in Java

Tags: java, rest, rally

We are trying to automate the project migration from one Rally workspace to other. Everything seems to work fine like we are able to migrate project and related releases/iterations/userstories/tasks from one workspace to another workspace.
But while trying to migrate BE Initiative/BE Feature/CPM Feature we are getting some exception related to Null Pointer exception but the error we are getting in Response doesn't seem to give much info.

A sample of code is -

```
    String oldProjectObjectId = "12345";
    String  newProjectObjectId = "67890";

    String oldRallyWorkspaceObjectId = "32145";
    String newRallyWorkspaceObjectId = "67894";
    QueryResponse beInitiativeResponse = queryRally("portfolioitem/beinitiative", "/project/"+this.oldProjectObjectId, "/workspace/"+this.oldRallyWorkspaceObjectId);

    int beInitiativeCount = beInitiativeResponse.getTotalResultCount();

    if(beInitiativeCount >0){

        JsonArray initiativeArray = beInitiativeResponse.getResults();

        for(int i=0; i< initiativeArray.size();i++){        

            JsonObject beInitiativeObject = initiativeArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

            String oldBeInitiativeObjectId = beInitiativeObject.get("ObjectID").getAsString();
            String oldBeInitiativeName = beInitiativeObject.get("_refObjectName").getAsString();

            String owner = getObjectId(beInitiativeObject, "Owner");

            JsonObject BeInitiativeCreateObject = getJsonObject(oldBeInitiativeName, "/project/"+this.newProjectObjectId, "/workspace/"+this.newRallyWorkspaceObjectId, owner);
            CreateResponse beInitiativeCreateResponse = createInRally("portfolioitem/beinitiative", BeInitiativeCreateObject);

            if(beInitiativeCreateResponse.wasSuccessful()){
                String newBeInitiativeObjectId = beInitiativeCreateResponse.getObject().get("ObjectID").getAsString();

                String mapKey = oldBeInitiativeObjectId;
                String mapValue= newBeInitiativeObjectId;
                this.beInitiativesHashMap.put(mapKey, mapValue);
            }
            else{   
                String[] errorList;
                errorList = beInitiativeCreateResponse.getErrors();
                for (int j = 0; j < errorList.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(errorList[j]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

queryRally and createInRally functions use **Rally rest client** to fetch and create the required projects and associated attributes like releases, iterations etc.

After executing `CreateResponse beInitiativeCreateResponse = createInRally("portfolioitem/beinitiative", BeInitiativeCreateObject);` when it's trying to execute `if(beInitiativeCreateResponse.wasSuccessful())` it is instead going to **else block** and thus printing the below mentioned error.

> > An unexpected error has occurred.
> > We have recorded this error and will begin to investigate it.  In the meantime, if you would like to speak with our Support Team, please reference the information below:
> > java.lang.NullPointerException
> > 2017-12-05 11:01 AM PST America/Los_Angeles

But the **important** point that is when trying to migrate projects and it's related attributes like release/iterations etc. withing same Rally workspace the above piece of code works just fine.

**Update1:**

While analysing the issue I made the following observations -

The workspace in which I am trying to create the BeInitiative doesn't have BEinitiative, Be Feature, CPM Feature options in Portfolio items dropdown. Rather it has Theme, Initiative and Feature options in it.
Therefore, I think I was getting the previouly mentioned error. Now I made the following changes to the code.

```
CreateResponse beInitiativeCreateResponse = createInRally("portfolioitem/theme", themeCreateObject);
```

So now instead of creating the BEInitiative I am trying to create the theme only in new workspace but getting the following error -

> Requested type name \"/portfolioitem/theme\" is unknown.

The object that i am passing to CreateResponse function is -

```
{"Name":"xyz","Project":"/project/1804","Workspace":"/workspace/139"}
```

Also code for createInRally function is as mentioned below -

```
public CreateResponse createInRally( String query, JsonObject object) throws IOException{

    CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest(query, object);

    CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);

    return createResponse;
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  Which line above is failing with that error?

Comment: Sorry for not pointing that out in the question itself.
when trying to execute 
`if(beInitiativeCreateResponse.wasSuccessful())`
Instead it's going to else block and thus executing 
               `else{
               String[] errorList;
                errorList = beInitiativeCreateResponse.getErrors();
                for (int j = 0; j < errorList.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(errorList[j]);
                }}`

Comment: Updated the same in the question also.

Comment: @KyleMorse could you please look into the issue as I have updated it with the info. required. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Unknown Type** error was occurring as a result of not passing the workspace's object id in which we were trying to create the portfolio item.
So after modifying the createInRally function to include the workspace object id we were able to create the initiative portfolio item.
The modified createInRally function is as shown below-

```
    CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest(query, object);

    createRequest.addParam("workspace", "/workspace/1333333333");

    CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);

    return createResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is definitely an error in the web services api.  You should never get 500 responses with an unhandled nullpointer.  My initial guess is that when you're creating your new object some field on it is still referencing an object in the old workspace, and when we try to correctly hook up all the associations it fails to read one of those objects in the new workspace.  Can you provide some more information about what your actual object you're sending to create looks like?  Specifically what object relationships are you including (that may not be valid in the new workspace)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have updated the question with the required info. under Update 1 heading.